# take a list from a directory and remove files in another directory with same names in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to take a list in a directory like: `ls /root/test` and then have a list variable that deletes the files in another directory like: `/root/test2`

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: take a list in test dir
    find:
      paths: /root/test
    register: files_to_delete

  - name: Ansible delete files in test2 path
    file:
      path: /root/test2/{{item}}
      state: absent
    with_items: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"
```

I couldn't find a guide anywhere and this method has not worked, I would appreciate it if someone can help me fix this issue.

Comment: `I couldn't find a guide anywhere` <= You can start by reading the [documentation for the `find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html)  which documents the returned values. You can also [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) the registered var to see its content. You can read the page for [available filters to manage file and path names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names)

Comment: And this should lead you to the conclusion that in your loop, you're looking for: `path: /root/test2/{{ item.path | basename }}`

Comment: i looked there but couldn't solve this issue but you made me too look there more specific and i found it thank you @Zeitounator

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Zeitounator I read docs and solved it:

```yaml
  - name: Ansible delete file glob
    find:
      paths: /root/test
      pattern: "*.txt"
    register: files_to_delete

  - debug: var={{item}}
    with_items: files_to_delete

  - name: Ansible remove file glob
    file:
      path: /root/test2/{{ item.path | basename }}
      state: absent
    with_items: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"
```